# How to count the top 3 occurrence letter in a string in Java

Tags: java

Here is my code...It kind of works until I try something like "June, July and August" ..it gives me 4 u,2 n,1 d instead of 4 u, 2 J, 2 n. I can't figure it out why...

And how can I output "non-alphabetical" when I input " " or "!@*(&$!(@^$"? I try to put it in the else statement in the end but I end up getting 1 d, non-alphabetical when I input d$&*#&$(*#@.

Also, when I input "hi" or "a" , I want to get a result like "1h,1i" and "1a" but not "1h,1i," and "1a,"

Sorry...I really can't figure it out how to do the above things... thanks for helping me..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pre {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter something: ");
    String myStr ;
    myStr = input.nextLine();
    int strLen = myStr.length();
    int[] freq = new int[160];
    char strChar;

    for (int i=0; i<strLen; i++) {
    strChar = myStr.charAt(i);
    //System.out.print(strChar + " ");
    for (char ch=65; ch<=122; ch++) {
         if (ch == strChar) {
            if ((ch >=65 && ch<=90)|| (ch>=97&&ch<=122)) {
                freq[ch]++;
                //System.out.println(freq[ch]);

     }else {
         System.out.println("Non-alphabetical String!");
     }
        }
            }                   
  }
             int[] maxArray = new int[160];
             char[] maxCharArray = new char[160];

             for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
                 maxArray[i]=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                 for (char ch=65; ch<=122; ch++) {

                if (freq[ch] > maxArray[i]) {
                maxArray[i] = freq[ch];
                maxCharArray[i] = ch;    
                freq[ch]=0;
                 }  
             }
             }
             PrintString(myStr,maxCharArray,maxArray);



}
public static void PrintString(String Mystr, char[] maxCharArray , int[] maxArray ) {
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
         if (maxArray[i] != 0) {
             System.out.print(maxArray[i] + " " +maxCharArray[i]);
             if(i!=2){
                 System.out.print (",");
             }

     } 
         //else{
             //System.out.println("Non-alphabetical String!");
             //break;
     //}
}

}
```

}

Comment: Can you use Java 8?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Comment: I really do not get the people who downvote questions like this. The person is asking for help  and asking for another point of view to figure the things out. I can not see any reason for downvoting here . The site editors should keep track of these people who downvotes  all the time and do sth  for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do is

```
    int count[] = new int[256];
    int len = str.length();
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        count[str.charAt(i)]++;
    int max = -1;
    char result = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (max < count[str.charAt(i)]) {
            max = count[str.charAt(i)];
            result = str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Here we are checking on the basis of ascii characters, which are 256.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I need 3 char not 1 but still thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of code, which is never a good thing.
Here's a one-liner:

```
myStr.chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
    .limit(3)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```